# Ruby class variable instance variable bug

Tags: ruby, oop, instantiation, instance-variables, class-variables

`Game` has an array of ten `Frame` instances

```
class Frame
  attr_accessor :rolls
  def initialize
    @rolls = ""
  end
  
end

class Game
  attr_accessor :frames
  def initialize
    @frames = Array.new(10, Frame.new) 
  end
  
  def print_frames
    @frames.each_with_index do |frame, idx|
      p "Frame ##{idx+1}: #{frame.rolls}"
    end
  end
end

game = Game.new

rolls = [5, 5, 3, 7, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]

curr = 0
rolls.each_with_index do |roll|
  game.frames[curr].rolls << roll.to_s
  if game.frames[curr].rolls.size == 2
    curr += 1
  end
end

p "Total rolls: #{rolls.size}"
p game.print_frames
```

I expect 10 lines to be printed, each line has a frame id with a string of 2 numbers
however, the following is returned

```
"Total rolls: 20"
"Frame #1: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #2: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #3: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #4: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #5: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #6: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #7: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #8: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #9: 55374000000000000022"
"Frame #10: 55374000000000000022"
[#<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">, #<Frame:0x0000565402e40528 @rolls="55374000000000000022">]
```

instance variable is acting like class variables shared between frames. all 20 rolls numbers are concatenated instead of each frame owning a pair.
what is wrong with the code? is it because the `Game` or `Frame` object is not instantiated correctly?

Comment: Try `@frames = Array.new(10) { Frame.new }` instead.

Comment: Tip: When getting bizarre results like this, do a little debugging with `p @frames.map(&:object_id)` to see if you have an array of identical object references, or different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Array.new(10, Frame.new)
```

Creates an array with 10 elements all pointing to a single `Frame` instance. To create an array with 10 separate `Frame` instances you should use the block form.

```
Array.new(10) { Frame.new }
```

This executes the block 10 times and assigns the result of each execution to the cosponsoring index.

See: [Creating Arrays](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays)

> An array can also be created by explicitly calling [`::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-c-new) with zero,
> one (the initial size of the [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html)) or two arguments (the initial size
> and a default object).
>
> ```
> ary = Array.new    #=> []
> Array.new(3)       #=> [nil, nil, nil]
> Array.new(3, true) #=> [true, true, true]
> ```
>
> **Note that the second argument populates the array with references to
> the same object.** Therefore, it is only recommended in cases when you
> need to instantiate arrays with natively immutable objects such as
> Symbols, numbers, true or false.
>
> To create an array with separate objects a block can be passed
> instead. This method is safe to use with mutable objects such as
> hashes, strings or other arrays:
>
> ```
> Array.new(4) {Hash.new}    #=> [{}, {}, {}, {}]
> Array.new(4) {|i| i.to_s } #=> ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
> ```

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree, the documentation should include an example of what this means in practice. This is quite a common pitfall.

Comment: There used to be a [common gotchas](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) section in the 2.7 docs. Unfortunately it was removed in the Ruby 3 docs.

Answer (score 1):

The method Array.new it's defined as new(size=0, default=nil) that means the second argument would be the value for all the objects inside the array, default value.

that's why for your case all 10 objects are the same.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new

this snippet code could help you to resolve

```rb
@frames = []
10.times {|i| @frames.push(rand) }
=> [0.7053319996471655, 0.34131818323294594, 0.4084836724883256, 0.20452172335941388, 0.5124065818560665, 0.4203474973940552, 0.6719502264788891, 0.7453268015406016, 0.09500886225101768, 0.9053707563920769]

# try this for your case
# 10.times {|i| @frames.push(Frame.new) } 

# using array creation with block
# ty tadman for the advice
# @frames = Array.new(10) { Frame.new }
```

Comment: Yes, but no. You can just use a block constructor. No need for the other mess.

Comment: @tadman jejejej yeah! you are right, i'll added that option to the snippet code, ty for the advice